# Make a function

Tags: pandas

I have this function:

```
def gnumeric_func (data, columns):
  data[columns] = data[columns].apply(lambda x: pd.factorize(x)[0])
  return data
column_list = data.iloc[:, 7:14]
gnumeric_func (data, column_list)
```

How to implement iloc without causing any errors like this:

```
 Must pass DataFrame with boolean values only
```

Comment: @jezrael, thank you a lot!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think help this sample:

```
df = pd.DataFrame({'A':list('abcdef'),
                   'B':[4,5,4,5,5,4],
                   'C':[7,8,9,4,2,3],
                   'D':list('aaabbb'),
                   'E':list('autrob'),
                   'F':list('etreeb')})

print (df)
   A  B  C  D  E  F
0  a  4  7  a  a  e
1  b  5  8  a  u  t
2  c  4  9  a  t  r
3  d  5  4  b  r  e
4  e  5  2  b  o  e
5  f  4  3  b  b  b

def gnumeric_func (data, columns):
  data[columns] = data[columns].apply(lambda x: pd.factorize(x)[0])
  return data

#select columns names by positions
column_list = df.columns[3:5]
print (column_list)
Index(['D', 'E'], dtype='object')

df2 = gnumeric_func(df, column_list)
print (df2)
   A  B  C  D  E  F
0  a  4  7  0  0  e
1  b  5  8  0  1  t
2  c  4  9  0  2  r
3  d  5  4  1  3  e
4  e  5  2  1  4  e
5  f  4  3  1  5  b
```